# Proxy and rewrite to WebApp

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, reverse-proxy

I'm running a webapp on local using gunicorn on `127.0.0.1:8000`. I want to make its service-page `/demo` accessible on `http://127.0.0.1/internal` and rewrite all calls to */demo* to *internal*

I'm using Apache v2.4.

Several approaches using `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite`.

```
# This gives me `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.
    <Location /internal>
        ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000/demo
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/demo
        RequestHeader    add X-Script-Name "/internal"
    </Location>

# This works, but I need to visit /internal/demo manually.
    <Location /internal>
        ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000
        RequestHeader    add X-Script-Name "/internal"
    </Location>
```

It doesn't matter, where to place the ProxyPass...

```
    ProxyPass        /internal http://localhost:8000
    ProxyPassReverse /internal http://localhost:8000
    <Location /internal>
        RequestHeader    add X-Script-Name "/internal"
    </Location>
```

According to the developer, `RequestHeader add X-Script-Name` is supported.

Using NGINX, this works as expected:

```
    location /internal {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /internal;
        rewrite /internal$ /internal/demo redirect;
    }
```

But adding this to Apache2 doesn't help:

```
RewriteRule   /internal$ /internal/demo [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems You want to achieve two things:

1. make your application visible to the users under the url path `/internal/` instead of `/`.
2. move the `/demo/` subfolder of your application up to the root `/` of your application (as far as the view of the users is concerned).

To achieve (1) I would try this one:

```
<Location /internal>
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000/internal
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/internal
    RequestHeader    add X-Script-Name "/internal"
</Location>
```

And then to achieve (2) I would just let apache proxy do the job:

```
<Location /internal>
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000/internal/demo
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/internal/demo
    RequestHeader    add X-Script-Name "/internal"
</Location>
```

Caveat: I just found out, by accident, that solution to (1), and it does exactly what I wanted to achieve, but I do not yet understand *why* it works.